# Subclass cannot update abstract superclass member variables

Tags: variables, abstract, member

I looked within the posted questions here, and did not find this particular situation discussed.

My code is much more complicated than this, but the problem seems to boil down to just these elements:

```
public abstract class AbstractSuper {
    protected List<String> supersList = new ArrayList<String();
    public AbstractSuper (int someArg) {
        initList();
    }
    protected abstract void initList();
    public int getListCount() {
        return supersList.size();
    }
}

public class ConcreteChild extends AbstractSuper {
    public ConcreteChild (int someArg) {
        super(someArg);
    }
    @Override
    protected void initList() {
        supersList = Arrays.asList("Test String");
    }
}
```

How can it be that any call to getListCount() after a ConcreteChild instance has been constructed returns 0?

The child's overriding method clearly sets the member variables to a non-zero array during construction.

Getting a zero for the variable array length from Java after having constructed the concrete class in such a way that the variable is pointing to a non-zero length array is VERY non-inituitive.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Did you mean `return supersList.size();` in `getListCount()` ?

Comment: Yes. Fixed that. Thank you. Question still applies.

Comment: Stepping through the code with a debugger is likely to show you where you're going wrong.  Without seeing the code from which you're getting the unexpected value makes it more difficult to answer this question.

Comment: I run the above code but got `1` from `getListCount()`. You problem might lie somewhere else. Are you sure your `"Test String"` is not an empty array?

Comment: I will see how much closer I can get this to my actual code without putting proprietary or impractically large amounts of code up here for folks to analyze. The problem may be that this is actually code that gets compiled by GWT into JavaScript, so perhaps there is a difference in how it works once it is running as GWT constructs within the browser's JS engine.